# How to set a href to bootstrap navbar onclick menu it should trigger to tabbar of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web

I have explain my query with this code. here when i click on dropdown navbar page should redirect to the tabbar available on another page.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a id="tab1" href="Page-3.html#tab1">Page 3-tab1</a></li>
          **<!-- Onclick "page3-tab1" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab1 activated -->**
          <li><a id="tab2" href="Page-3.html#tab2">Page 3-tab2</a></li>
           **<!-- Onclick "page3-tab2" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab2 activated -->**
          <li><a id="tab3" href="Page-3.html#tab3">Page 3-tab3</a></li>
          **<!-- Onclick "page3-tab3" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab3 activated -->**
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
      <!-- Page 3 Contains one  tabbar having 3 tabs -->
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Page-3.html contains a tabbar should be activated and redirect on screen on click menubar.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab">Tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab">Tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" role="tab">Tab3<br></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
     <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Tab 3</h3>
     <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am new in jquery and it can be done through javascript/jquery. But i dont know exactly how to do it. So,please can anyone help me??Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is the relevant `javascript/jQuery` to go with your question?

Comment: i didnt code for javascript/jquery because i am not getting idea how to solve it.

Comment: Well without existing `javascript` or `jQuery` this is no doubt not driven by it so for this to work you will no doubt have to save `Page-3.html` with the relevant changes to your element with the id of  `night` and save it with a `class` of `active` and remove the one set for `day` but you will need to do this for each page. If you want to have this so it's dynamic and driven by `javascript`/ `jQuery` then you must make some form of attempt before I can offer you a solution since right now I have nothing to solve as nothing is broken.

Comment: can you provide me jquery code to trigger on another page and activate particulate tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to make this work.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
              <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1-1</a></li>
                <li><a id="tab1" href="Page-3.html#menu1">Page 3-tab1</a></li>
                <!-- Onclick "page3-tab1" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab1 activated -->
                <li><a id="tab2" href="Page-3.html#menu2">Page 3-tab2</a></li>
                 <!-- Onclick "page3-tab2" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab2 activated -->
                <li><a id="tab3" href="Page-3.html#menu3">Page 3-tab3</a></li>
                <!-- Onclick "page3-tab3" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab3 activated -->
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            <!-- Page 3 Contains one  tabbar having 3 tabs -->
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
```

And then in page-3

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
              <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="gototab1">Page 3-tab1</a></li>
                <!-- Onclick "page3-tab1" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab1 activated -->
                <li><a href="#" id="gototab2">Page 3-tab2</a></li>
                 <!-- Onclick "page3-tab2" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab2 activated -->
                <li><a href="#" id="gototab3">Page 3-tab3</a></li>
                <!-- Onclick "page3-tab3" it should redirect to page3 should be displayed tab3 activated -->
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            <!-- Page 3 Contains one  tabbar having 3 tabs -->
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>
       <h1>page 3</h1>       
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs"  id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Tab2</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Tab3</a></li>  
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>Tab 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in tab 1.</p>
      </div>    

        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Tab 2</h3>
           <p>Some content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3>Tab 3</h3>
           <p>Some content.</p>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {            
        var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );
        console.log(hash);

        var thisLink = $('a[href="'+hash+'"]');
        console.log(thisLink.parent());
        hash = hash.substring(1);

        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(thisLink.parent()).addClass("active");
        $("#"+hash).addClass(" in active");

        $('#gototab1').click(function() {
            $('#myTab a[href="#menu1"]').tab('show');
        });

        $('#gototab2').click(function() {
            $('#myTab a[href="#menu2"]').tab('show');
        });

        $('#gototab3').click(function() {
            $('#myTab a[href="#menu3"]').tab('show');
        });            

    }); //end of document ready 

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me your important time..but this code is not working.

Comment: Did you include jquery and bootstrap scripts? Because it does work for me.

Comment: when i run your code, first thing no tab-bar is active and onclick menutab page3tab1/2/3, it not showing any activity....

And here i wants to redirect to another page and there appropriate tab should active.

Comment: Did you notice I have changed tab names to menu1 , menu2, menu3 etc.. Please copy paste the above nav bar code in your other pages and rest is all for page 3.

Comment: what if i have use common navbar to all pages?

Comment: You can use common navbar in all the pages except page3. In that if you use common navbar, then on click of navbar link leading to the tabs in the same page does not work. You may have to use different jquery for that.